# ASP.NET Core Web API - JSON Ignore not working in Core-6 Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I am implementing Json Ignore in Swagger.

I have this code:

```
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAuthorize = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() ||
            context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

        if (!hasAuthorize) 
            return;

        operation.Responses.TryAdd("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized - not authenticated" });
        operation.Responses.TryAdd("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden - not authorized" });

        var bearerScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        };

        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                [bearerScheme] = new [] {""}
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then I did the configuration in `Program.cs` as shown here:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
var environment = builder.Environment;
var swaggerDocOptions = new SwaggerDocOptions();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(op => op.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
        = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>()
    .Configure<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>((swagger, service) =>
    {
        foreach (ApiVersionDescription description in service.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            swagger.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = swaggerDocOptions.Title,
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                Description = swaggerDocOptions.Description,
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://myapp.com/LICENSE.md"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = swaggerDocOptions.Organization,
                    Email = swaggerDocOptions.Email
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "MIT",
                    Url = new Uri("https://myapp.com/kkj")
                }
            });
        }

        var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {"Bearer", new string[0]}
        };

        swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT"
        });

        swagger.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();

        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        swagger.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

    });
// Register and Configure API versioning
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

// Register and configure API versioning explorer
builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;

});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And finally, I apply it in the model class like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool? IsPasswordChanged { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I expected that `IsPasswordChanged` and `IsDeleted` shouldn't appear in Swagger, but they still appear despite the JSON Ignore.

Where have I missed it and how do I correct this?

Thank you

Comment: But wait, you show your entity and you put the attribute on your entity. Where are your DTOs? Or are you directly exposing your Identity entity on your API?? That sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @JHBonarius - That's the DTO

Comment: Check whether you're using `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`. It's possible that one is being used to serialise but your attribute is from the other.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough - I used Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichardBarraclough. When I changed Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json it works

Answer (score 1):

There is the `[OpenApiIgnore]` attribute in the `NSwag.Annotations` namespace for AspNetCore. It appears to work on a class or a method and excludes them from the generated Swagger document. You will need to include the `NSwag.AspNetCore` package from NuGet.

Comment: For Swashbuckle its `[SwaggerIgnore]` i think.

Comment: @JHBonarius - When I installed NSwag.AspNetCore package from NuGet I got this error:     Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger      and   app.UseSwagger() is highlighted in Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem. Using `[JsonIgnore]` in the `Newtonsoft.Json`.
If you use `[FromForm]`, use must to use `[OpenApiIgnore]` in the `NSwag.Annotations`.